# Keep neighbors seperated SwiftUI .scaleEffect

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI's `.scaleEffect` scales views over their neighbors in `VStack`s and `HStack`s. How can I scale a view while keeping the view and its neighbors seperated vertically / horizontally?

Sample Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Left Text")
            Text("Middle Text")
                .scaleEffect(2)
            Text("Right Text")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible, scaleEffect modifier does not modify the frame of view! May you working on changing Font size in a custom view.

Comment: Why not just change the font size or the view's frame size?

Comment: In my actual app, I can't use font size as it's not a text view that I'm scaling. But the frame is a good idea. I'll see if I can make that work